# FuelUX Tree: Load expanded folder as a child of another folder

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel

I have the following items in fuelux tree:

```
+ folder1
+ folder2
```

After clicking **folder1**, I want to load **folder1** children (subfolder1, subfolder2) with their children and make **subfolder1** to be expanded automatically:

```
- folder1
	- subfolder1
		 item1
		 item2
	+ subfolder2
+ folder2
```

How this can be done?
Passing the following JSON object to Datasource callback adds only subfolder1 and subfolder2 to tree:

```
    {"data": [
        {"name":"subfolder1","type":"folder", "children": [
            {"name":"item1","type":"item"},{"name":"item2","type":"item"}]
        },
        {"name":"subfolder2","type":"folder"}]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer that contributed the tree control to the fuel library. Currently there is no way of expanding sub folders when clicking on a parent folder. This is however a great idea for a feature!

We are working towards the release of fuel 3 (a fuel library upgrade that will be compatible with bootstrap 3). I will add this feature to the tree control and direct you to my pull request for this feature when it is done sometime this week.

thank you for the feedback

Comment: David, The question expanding sub folders was resolved? Tks