# Fuelux tree open when loaded to the preselected items

Tags: marketing-cloud, jquery, fuel

I am trying to get the tree open from one node upwards to the root when the tree is loaded, and I don´t find the way to do it. 
It´s useful in the case that as soon as the tree is loaded, I am able to see the path to the preselected nodes.

Please tell me the way to achieve this, in case it´s possible, if not please take it mind for next releases.

Regards

Comment: Hi César, how does this question relate to SalesForce?

Comment: ok, sorry, I just saw other post related: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30203/fuelux-tree-load-expanded-folder-as-a-child-of-another-folder

Comment: Reopen this, as its an Exacttarget question..